# Performance of using many parameters in constructor

Tags: java, android, performance, constructor

Does any one know what is the performance impact when using many parameters in constructor (10+) compared to setters?

I my case the model object is not valid without any of those parameters, so I am using single constructor.

I know that there is not significant difference either way, but I am asking if anyone knows whats actually going on in both cases.

I am asking for performance because the application is Android application that can be run on older devices without JIT.

Also it would be nice if we know the optimal solution.

Comment: Check out [Effective Java - Creating and Destroying Objects](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02) -> Item 2.

Comment: Why don't you write a test, and measure yourself?

Comment: As you said, there is not significant difference in terms of performance. In terms of encapsulation and correctness, there is a significant difference, though.

Comment: This link does not address the question asked.

Comment: Use Builder pattern when dealing with 4+ Params.

Comment: it's the best pointer for Constructing objects with many parameters that I know of. It does not tackle performance, but it gives other pointers, which are also important. The person that asks the question shall decide if this link helps him in some way or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance implication of using the setters vs. the constructor is negligible, because roughly the same thing is going on in both instances: data passed to a method gets stored in an instance variable.

With ten setters you pay the price for nine additional method calls, but they are so extremely cheap that you are not likely to find any difference, especially if they get inlined by JIT compiler.

Logical implications are a lot more severe: if your object is not valid until you set all ten instance variables, then you definitely need to use a constructor with ten parameters: performance gains, real or not, are secondary to the logical integrity of your class, which should not be compromised.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Getters are cheap on devices with JIT, but on one without not so much. I have measured difference about 1s on every 15000 getter calls compared with using only constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, if you have such a situation, it's a clear indication that your code needs (some) refactoring. None of the 2 solutions are good (i.e. big parameter list in constructor vs. setters). Also, given the fact that you can't force the clients of that object to call the setters, some runtime errors can easily occur because of this.

As for the performance part: no, performance impacts don't happen because of this. There is no reason why it should.

Comment: In some situations a big parameter list is just the right thing. If you know them all when constructing your object, which isn't divided into less objects, just do it. I've seen insurance contract classes, which had much more attributes.

Comment: I agree with the statement that setters are not good for this situation for the reasons that you mention. I don't agree with the refactoring part, sometimes constructor with many parameters is just what's needed. Probably for now the best solution is the builder pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can encapsulate all the parameters in a single object, and pass it as a parameter to your constructor.

Comment: That wouldn't solve anything. Because that encapsulating object will have to be created the same way. By doing that, the problem is not solved, it's just moved to another class.

Comment: @SoboLAN Why does it have to be created the same way? You can build such an object step by step and finally pass it to the constructor. Nevertheless a builder pattern is more flexible but is doing something similar when you call builder's methods and finally its build() method. Both are collecting data that is necessary to create an object at the end.

Comment: @FabianBarney Damn, forgot about the Build Pattern. Yes, that would work.

Comment: Encapsulating the parameters is not the right choice for my situation. This would mean +1 object creation (expensive on android) and calling 10+ getters.

Comment: You did not write you want for Android. But now I can see your point.
My idea was from a design point of view.